# how to format html code in visual studio 2019

Tags: html, visual-studio-2019

For some reason when I tried to paste text into an html file in VS 2019 not all of the text was included. I added a text file to my VS project, pasted all the text, then saved it as an html file. How do I format the html file? I tried this but it didn't format the text to html format.

To format a selection: `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F`

To format a document: `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D`

When I delete the `<!DOCTYPE html>` from the text file, save it as an html file, then import it into VS I can format the selected text with `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F`. But it strips everything, div tags and all. It leaves the .js files inside script tags.